# Fetching records that are not being updated SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, memory-optimized-tables

I have an API that multiple processor requests work from. The job of the the API is to select records from a memory optimized table and mark the status assigned and hand it off to the requester. I have multiple processor that could request work at the same time and we keep getting this contention

```
Error Message :- The current transaction attempted to update a record that has been updated since this transaction started. The transaction was aborted.
```

How do i overcome this issue?

Here is a example of the GetWork method in the API

```
update memtabletemp set memtabletemp.status = 'ASSIGNED' , memtabletemp.statustimestamp = current_timestamp
                 OUTPUT INSERTED.memid,INSERTED.recordtype from(select top 5 memid, recordtype,status,statustimestamp from
                   memtable where status = 'READY')memtabletemp
```

Comment: The issue is related to a `transaction`.  So you should post the entire `transaction` being ran.

Comment: The SQL I posted, is what is in the API to get Work.